# Чтение дампа mysql.sql как базы

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго. Научите нуба

Представьте что дамп БД (super_baza.sql) валяется прямо на хостинге. ЕЕ конечно можно импортировать в бд и пользоваться, но знаю что (при всех минусах) ей можно пользоваться/редактировать без импорта в бд. При гуглении - как обычно забанили. А если серьезно то в основном инфа про то как этот бамп сделать или как пользоваться mysql.

Может кто подсказать, слова для гугления или статьи, где описано обращение к файлу с дампом БД mysql.sql, и использование его как БД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работа с текстовыми файлами [Тыц1](http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=fs&page=005)

Preg_match [Тыц2](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/ref.pcre.php)

Регулярные выражения [Тыц3](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

Для не одноразового доступа к данным скорее всего понадобиться создавать доп файлы с индексами базы ( список таблиц и их расположение в файле, количество полей и их имена). Получится такой мини аналог мускульного клиента InnoDB. Но скорость работы такого приложения будет очень низкой.

Как вариант поковыряйте исходники phpMyAdmin.

И ещё - Месье знает толк в извращениях.

Comment: ну, скажем так. Для mysql - решения готового нет, для mysqli - есть. Но т.к. надо mysql, буду изобретать велосипед

Comment: mysqli  - это же и есть php драйвер для mysql!!! Или вы думаете что это две различных базы данных?

Answer (score 2):

Вы какую то глупость придумали.
Поясните цель этого мероприятия. Может я чет не то понял...

Comment: "в yii до вноса параметров БД, сам yii пользуется mysqli." не понял. 
У вас не получается работа с базой данных в YII?

Comment: Дамп базы не являетяс базой! это подготовленные выражения, для того, чтобы вставить эти данные в базу.

Comment: просто привел пример,что использование дампа БД как бд - возможно. но как? следующий ответ будет - пользуйтесь yii.. хотя вопрос не про него совсем. про то, что использование базы и использование отдельно этого файла разные вещи - сам понимаю

Comment: написать парсер, который занесет все данные из ДАМПА в массив и будет такая структура:

    data = array(
    'table1'=>array(
    array('column1'=>'test data','column2'=>'test data'),
    array('column1'=>'test text','column2'=>'test text'),
    );
    );


Но блин, это делать можно только в случае мирового апокалипсиса, когда кроме твоего  ноута, php , и этого дампа ничего не осталось )

Вы представьте как будет парсится ваш дамп на гигов 10 ) да пусть даже на на 100 мб. 
И как вы собираетесь искать по такому массиву?

Comment: А чем вам mysqli не нравится?

Comment: Да всем нравиться, только что для нее, что для mysql - не могу найти решения как использовать дамп БД из файла